# Magento discount coupon code created on fly but not working properly

Tags: magento

Here is my code which create the coupon code on the fly:

```
$productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
        $discountprice=$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
        $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
        $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
        $model->setName($couponCode);
        $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
        $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
        $model->setIsActive(1);
       // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
        $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
        $model->setProductIds($productId);
        $model->setSortOrder(1);
        $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
        $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
        $model->setDiscountStep(0);
        $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
        $model->setTimesUsed(0);
        $model->setIsRss(0);
        $model->setWebsiteIds('1');
        $model->save();
```

but when I checkout particular product the discount apply automatically, my requirement is the discount must be apply after I enter the code in the Discount Codes box, also when I enter the code in Discount Codes it shows the code is not valid...

Please help anyone. I am also trying my best to solve this; if I find any solution I'll put here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');
function generateUniqueId($length = null)
{
    $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
    $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
    $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
    $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
        if (!is_null($rndId)){
        return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
        }
    return strtoupper($rndId);
}
/* create unique coupon code */
for($cc = 0 ; $cc<15 ; $cc++){
    $productId  = 297;//(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
    $discountprice= 1;//$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
    $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
    $model->setName($couponCode);
    $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
    $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
    $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
    $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
    $model->setIsActive(1);
   // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
    $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
   // $model->setProductIds($productId);
    $model->setSortOrder('0');
    $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
    $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
    $model->setDiscountStep(0);
    $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
    $model->setCouponType(2);
    $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
    $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
    $model->setTimesUsed(0);
    $model->setIsRss(0);
    $model->setWebsiteIds('1');
    $model->save();
    }
    echo 'ok';
```

This is my code to create 1000 coupons.

1. put $model->save(); outside the loop？
2. you should set a right $productId

Comment: small note: $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1) is doubled in the code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for viewing my question the answer code is here u can set the coupan code your self and apply it while checkout.

```
function generateUniqueId($length = null)
    {
        $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
        $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
        $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
        $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
            if (!is_null($rndId)){
            return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
            }
        return strtoupper($rndId);
    }
    /* create unique coupan code */

        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
        $discountprice=$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
        $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
        $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
        $model->setName($couponCode);
        $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
        $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
        $model->setIsActive(1);
       // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
        $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
       // $model->setProductIds($productId);
        $model->setSortOrder('0');
        $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
        $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
        $model->setDiscountStep(0);
        $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
        $model->setCouponType(2);
        $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setTimesUsed(0);
        $model->setIsRss(0);
        $model->setWebsiteIds('1');
        $model->save();
```