# Magento - Create Unique Coupon Codes through code and mail it to the customer

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I was wondering if there is a way through which one can create unique Discount Coupon codes every time through code or some script and mail it to different customers as per needed. Here's the script that I found over the net,

```
public function generateRuleAction()
{
    $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
    $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
    $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
    $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
    if (!is_null($rndId))
    {
        strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, 5));
    }

    $groups = array();
    foreach ($customerGroups as $group)
    {
        $groups[] = $group->getId();
    }

    $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
    $websiteIds = array();
    foreach ($websites as $website)
    {
        $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
    }

     $uniqueId = strtoupper($rndId);
     $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
     $rule->setName($uniqueId);
     $rule->setDescription('Generated for Test Purposes');
     $rule->setFromDate(date('Y-m-d'));//starting today
     //$rule->setToDate('2011-01-01');//if an expiration date's needed
     $rule->setCouponCode($uniqueId);
     $rule->setUsesPerCoupon(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon
     $rule->setUsesPerCustomer(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon for each customer
    $customerGroups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();

    $rule->setCustomerGroupIds($groups); 
    $rule->setIsActive(1);
    $rule->setStopRulesProcessing(0);//set to 1 if you want all other rules after this to not be processed
    $rule->setIsRss(0);//set to 1 if you want this rule to be public in rss
    $rule->setIsAdvanced(1);
    $rule->setProductIds('');   
    $rule->setSortOrder(0);// order in which the rules will be applied
    $rule->setSimpleAction('by_percent');

    $rule->setDiscountAmount('20');//the discount amount/percent. 
    //if SimpleAction is by_percent this value must be <= 100
    $rule->setDiscountQty(0);//Maximum Qty Discount is Applied to
    $rule->setDiscountStep(0);//used for buy_x_get_y; This is X
    $rule->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);//set to 1 for Free shipping
    $rule->setApplyToShipping(1);//set to 0 if you don't want the rule to be applied to shipping

    $rule->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds); 

    $conditions = array();
    $conditions[1] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => 1,
    'new_child' => ''
    );

    $conditions['1--1'] = Array
    (
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_address',
    'attribute' => 'base_subtotal',
    'operator' => '>=',
    'value' => 200
    );


    $labels = array();
    $labels[0] = 'Default store label';//default store label
    $labels[1] = 'Label for store with id 1';
    //....
    $labels[n] = 'Label for store with id n';
    //add one line for each store view you have. The key is the store view ID
    $rule->setData('conditions',$conditions);
    $rule->loadPost($rule->getData());
    $rule->setCouponType(2);
    $rule->setStoreLabels($labels);
    $rule->save();

}
```

This script creates a huge 26-letter unique code just about fine. I understand this code some what but not completely and hence do not know how to create a small 6-7 letter unique code each time and mail it to the customer. I am also not sure as to how I should go about mailing these codes to my customers.

Any input or suggestions would be well appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT :After writing the code @Jitendra provided, the coupon code works fine and gets created fine. Now how do I call this file in my function which is my module's IndexController.php? Also how do I mail this coupon code to each different customer based on the following condition:

```
$sample_model2 = Mage::getModel('sample/sample')->getCollection();
$sample_model2->addFieldToFilter('order_email_id', $customerEmail);
foreach($sample_model2 as $final_model1)
{   
echo '<br/>Email: ' . $final_model1['order_id'] . '<br/>';  
/*NEED SOME FUNCTION TO BE CALLED HERE TO CREATE UNIQUE COUPON CODE FOR EACH EMAIL ID AND MAIL THEM TO THE CUSTOMER*/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pleas check this i have also the same requirement you can use this code and modify it your own way..

[Magento discount coupan code created on fly but not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030887/magento-discount-coupan-code-created-on-fly-but-not-working-properly)

cheers...

Jeet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have more or less done the same thing and it does create a coupon code for me. I haven't used it yet to check whether its valid or not. But firstly I need to find out a method so as to how should I send unique coupon codes to my customers each time in a mail. Secondly I need to generate a small code as compared to the 26-letter code it creates for me now? Do you have any idea as to how can I achieve these two?

Comment: please check the code properly it contains all the requirement, you can pass the length of the code in the function see i have given 8 there.And as far as email concern you have to modify the code your way just sent this code in email and customer can use it in view cart page..

Comment: Can you tell me is you code written in a file or in a function of an existing file? And out of the two answers which answer should I take into account, the one by you or the by the other guy. I just used a code that I had created using above function, n it said 'Coupon invalid'. So hopefully with your code in the right place and the right file, I wont get 'Coupon Invalid' error.

Comment: Thanks @Jitendra! I created public_html/coupons.php from the link you had provided using your code. I executed this code by running http://mysite.com/coupons.php and a 6-letter coupon code was created. I applied that code and it worked fine giving 10% discount on my product which was exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: Now I'm left with two things, how do I call this method every time in my file so that it creates a new code each time. Secondly how do I mail this coupon code to the customer based on the condition I have in my question. Just edited the question.

Comment: first of all i would like to congratulate you for the code which is working fine and exactly what you want and make sure you always  accept the answer if it is helpful in your development this will help you in future to get better answer.Create the function of this code in your controller action file and for email you can create email template using magento or send a simple email to user containing the coupon code.. thanks...

Comment: Yes would definitely do that. If you don't mind can you show by an example as to what you mean by 'Create the function of this code in your controller action file' ? Since now you know where exactly this coupon code needs to be called in my code, can you by means of an example show me what do u mean by creating a function?

Comment: lolz:) you want me to develop whole code here, that's not possible here i have given code for development now you have to modify it your self thanks..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6819/discussion-between-ivn-and-jitendra)