# Creating a single random Magento coupon

Tags: php, magento, automation, auto-generate, coupon

I'm having some trouble. What I want to do is automatically generate a single random coupon code in Magento each time someone subscribes to our newsletter. The coupon is 10 dollars off anything and will have an exp. date of two weeks after subscription.

So, I'm trying to write a simple script that trips when the "subscribe to our newsletter" form is submitted that will talk to Magento, ask Magento for a single random coupon code, set a few basic price rules (10 bucks off anything, one use per customer, one use per coupon, expires two weeks from generation) and then return a random coupon code (ex:WELCOME5798) which can be stored in a variable that will be passed, along w/ first+last name and e-mail to MailChimp via the MailChimp API. I have all this figured out EXCEPT for how to get Mage to generate such a code via a PHP script and then return said code (i.e. I have my form and I know how to pass values to MailChimp).

I'm new to Magento, so I'm having a tough time. I've seen the code in Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon and I've seen some examples of people solving somewhat similar questions, such as here: [Magento - Create Unique Coupon Codes through code and mail it to the customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908347/magento-create-unique-coupon-codes-through-code-and-mail-it-to-the-customer)

But I'm really at a loss for where to start making this work for my own purposes. Could use some help/setting straight. :( Thanks folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what is your question? How to generate coupon for your requirements? Or how to arrange it in module?

You can use event newsletter_subscriber_save_after to inject your custom actions to the subscribe process.

Here is an example of coupon creation according to your needs

```
<?php
/**
 * Create coupon for fixed price discount
 *
 * @param int $customer_id
 * @param float $discount
 */
public function createCoupon($customer_id, $discount)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

    $customerGroupIds = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    $websitesId = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

    $customer_name = $customer->getName();
    $couponCode = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(9);

    $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $model->setName('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
    $model->setDescription('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
    $model->setFromDate(date('Y-m-d'));
    $model->setToDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days')));
    $model->setCouponType(2);
    $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
    $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
    $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
    $model->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroupIds);
    $model->setIsActive(1);
    $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    $model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
    $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
    $model->setProductIds('');
    $model->setSortOrder(1);
    $model->setSimpleAction('by_fixed');
    $model->setDiscountAmount($discount);
    $model->setDiscountStep(0);
    $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
    $model->setTimesUsed(0);
    $model->setIsRss(0);
    $model->setWebsiteIds($websitesId);

    try {
        $model->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I guess where I'm getting a little stuck is that I don't need to collect ANY customer info from our Magento database because all the customer info we need is sent directly to MailChimp via our form. All new subscribers will receive the coupon, so specifying customer groups isn't needed either. Sense I'm still pretty uncomfortable with Magento, I was planning on trying the quick and dirty route and actually writing the script to run outside of Mage using the ever useful `require_once('../app/Mage.php');`. I may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: I'm literally just trying to get Mage to create a random coupon (w/ the specified price rules) and send it back to be passed to the MailChimp API. Maybe I can't just just bypass adding it to a Mage module (again, inexperience here). But thanks for your help/patience Pavel, I will play with the code you provided!

Comment: in my example $customer_id is used only for generating coupon description. You can blank it out and add your own description to the setName() and setDescription() methods. Again returning to my code you have coupon code stored in the $couponCode variable so you can pass it to the email template

Comment: Pavel Novitsky, you're amazing. :) This is starting to make sense! I'm seeing it now. Thank you so so much!

Comment: for anybody else that runs into a problem with making a code. I had to add a line to set the store label: $model->setStoreLabels("Some Label");