# Deleting a large number of Magento coupons (shopping cart price rules) programatically

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento, coupon

I've been on here before asking about writing code to get Magento to generate a random coupon code for a new e-mail subscriber - [Creating a single random Magento coupon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806919/creating-a-single-random-magento-coupon)

This code worked perfectly and to those who helped I am eternally grateful. I am now looking for a way to delete these coupons as they expire in a bulk fashion because deleting them individually through the Magento admin is a huge pain. As you can see from the picture below, in the span of a couple of days we generated over 300 coupons (all now expired).

[image]

Would modifying the create coupon code detailed in the link (from my original question) above work? Something like:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
       $model->getName('New newsletter subscriber discount');
       $model->getToDate(date('Y-m-d'));
$model->delete();
```

Or am I totally barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but almost as soon as I posted, I was able to figure it out. So in case anyone else has a question like mine:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

// Requires Mage
require_once('../../app/Mage.php');

//Initializes Mage
Mage::app('default');
deleteCoupon();

function deleteCoupon() {
  $collection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->load();

  foreach($collection as $model) {

    // Delete all new newsletter sub coupons
    if ($model->getName() == 'New newsletter subscriber discount') {

    // Delete all coupons expiring today    
    if ($model->getToDate() == date('Y-m-d')) { 
      $model->delete();
      echo "Deleted <br />";
    } else {
      echo "No coupons found! <br />"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Helped me also, was looking for solution like this. Kudos

Comment: Does this code delete just the coupons? Or does it delete cart rules that these coupons apply too?